# How to change VS Code settings by active display size

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change the VS Code settings by active display size? For example, I would like to move the right panel to left increase font-size of the UI when I working on the Macbook and move the some panel to right and decrease font-size of the UI when I working on the 32" display.

Comment: create 2 Multi Root Workspaces with 1 folder/root, VSC remembers the setup per workspace, depending on the screen open a particular MRW

Comment: @rioV8 I don't use two different workstation for the development. I have a Macbook and a Dell 32" display. Sometimes I'm working on the Macbook with external monitor and sometimes I am using the Macbook without the external monitor. So, I just want to change VS Code UI depend on the active monitor's display size.

Comment: then depending which screen you use pick the right MR Workspace